# How to create and access 2d linked list elements

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create 2d Linked list. When i try to access its element, causes segmentation fault.

Here is part of the code

```
struct Node{
    char *data;
    int count;
    struct Pair *p;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Pair{
    char *data;
    int count;
    struct Pair *next;
};

void insertPairs(char *word1, char *word2, struct Node **head){
struct Node *ptr = *head;

while(ptr != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(ptr->data, word1) == 0){
        struct Pair *pairPtr = ptr->p;
        while(pairPtr != NULL){
            if(strcmp(pairPtr->data, word2) == 0){ //Segmentation Fault
                pairPtr->count = pairPtr->count + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        struct Pair *tmp = (struct Pair*) malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
        tmp->data = word2;
        tmp->count = 1;
        tmp->next = pairPtr;
        pairPtr = tmp;
        break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

}
```

I made some debugging.

This line gives me Segmentation Fault `if(strcmp(pairPtr->data, word2) == 0)`

Why is the `if(strcmp(ptr->data, word1) == 0)` working but above not? What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you provided I couldn't detect a problem. Is it possible that either `word2` or `pairPtr->data` are null pointers or are not pointers to null-terminated byte strings? In that case the behaviour is undefined and very much likely to cause a segmentation fault.

Check out: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: Problem is `pairPtr->data` but there is a `NULL` check in `while` statement so it shouldn't be `NULL`.

Comment: In the `while` statement you only verify that `pairPtr` isn't `NULL`. You don't verify that the `data` field in it isn't `NULL`.